# Is the summation of Euclidean distance a smooth function?

Tags: euclidean-algorithm, smooth-functions

Assuming I have 10 points (M1 , M2 .... Mn=10) that form a curve in three-dimensional space. Thus, Mi (XMi , YMi , ZMi).

To determine the distance from M1 to Mn, I have used the summation of the euclidean distances from i=1 to i=n using the normal Euclidean distance equation:

$$d= \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{(X_{i+1}-X_i)^2+(Y_{i+1}-Y_i)^2+(Z_{i+1}-Z_i)^2}$$

I would like to know if this function is a smooth function along these 10 points. Can someone present me with a reference on how to support the claim if it's either yes/no?

Comment: Huh?  $M_0,\dots,M_{10}$ is eleven points, not ten points.  And finite number of points don't form a curve.  Also, please use MathJax to format your post for clarity.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and also show the work you have done so far.

Comment: Yes true I updated it to start from M1 to M10. However, I don't think my question was understood. What I mean is that assuming we have a curve in 3D made up of any set of points (for simplicity assume 10). I wanted to calculate the distance to move from the first point of the curve to the last point on the curve. To do so, I used the summation of the euclidean distance between the points. Now, I need to know if this function is considered as smooth.

Comment: Except at the given ten points, the function is infinitely differentiable.

Comment: Can you please explain? I have updated the formula.

Comment: Do you mean $(X_{i+1}-X_i)^2$ (`(X_{i+1}-X_i)^2`) etc.?

Comment: Yes, thank you I updated the formula.